# FTP Scripting Capabilities

Tags: script, windows-server-2008-r2, ftps, ftp

I am looking for an FTP client that will allow me to do the following

- Include a GUI for setting up a number of FTP connections
- Support FTPS
- Run unattended on Windows Server 2008
- Retry failed transactions
- Support email
- Support custom scripts

I need to pull files from a few different servers and there are certain calculations that need to be done depending on which server the files come from.

I've looked at SmartFTP and it looks like pretty much what I need except I can't get it to run as a Windows Scheduled Task (I currently have some support threads open in their forum).

I've also looked at a few other FTP clients (Filezilla, RoboFTP, and AutoFTP (you can find the Windows 7 BSOD in this one!)) that haven't had the capabilities I'm looking for.

Right now, I'm looking at WS_FTP and its scripting capabilities. It appears I can create a script to run as a scheduled task, but I can't add the script to a file transfer task.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I can do post-transfer processing on the files or better yet how to integrate scripting into the file transfer task?

I'm also open to other suggestions for FTP clients as well if you have them!

If I can't find a suitable FTP client, custom scripting will just have to do the trick.

Comment: [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) supports batch jobs; but could you explain what do you mean by "* Support email" and why must the post-processing be done by the FTP client, when external programs are much more suitable?

Comment: The support email requirement means that it should send support sending email on, for example, an error. It would be preferable if the setting were at least customizable. 

The post-processing doesn't necessarily need to be done by the FTP client, but it is preferable for it to be done in one place. Right now, I'm just looking for a more friendly approach (maintenance-wise) to the current solution (a custom script that takes care of the FTP and processing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with SmartFTP. Although I received timely, useful help, I was disappointed they wouldn't give me a temporary license to work with scheduled tasks to see if the behavior was appropriate for my purposes. Luckily, it all worked out in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try Auto FTP Manager.  It is designed for automatic file transfers on a schedule and it logs all your transfers and any errors. Download the software here:
http://www.deskshare.com/ftp-client.aspx

Comment: I tried AutoFTP already and managed to get it to consistently blue screen, so I abandoned it :) Thanks though!